# How to achieve pressing against invisible wall effect facing camera? (animation)

Tags: animation, collision

i'm quite new to blender.

I'm making some animations and i would like to reproduce this effect

[image]

Not only for the tongue,any part of the body ( hand/foot/derrière/chest )

To resume ,a character pressing against invisible screen facing the camera with this " collission " effect for any part of the body touching that invisible screen.

(i have not found anything about rigged characters and collisions for animation )

Answer (score 9):

This is not a simulation but a similar effect can be obtained very simply with a shrinkwrap modifier:

[image]

Set the modifier to "Project" and "Outside" (if orientation faces the model / normal of it pointing to the monkey).

Axis the one of the glass normal. Direction: positive. Cull face is not needed.

I've added a subdivison after it to curve a bit vertices that are stretched by the glass.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 8 times against the wall that hard leads in a concussion for sure. Awww, poor suzanne :D

Comment: _"Sometimes you just feel like you're beating your  head against a brick wall."_

Answer (score 0):

Why not just...make an invisible wall?

- Add a plane object and position it appropriately.
- Give it a transparent shader. (If you're using Cycles, you can use a Transparent BSDF with a white color.)
- Add physics to make it affect other objects.

And that should be all it takes!

Comment: Because as i said i have not found anything that work for rigged characters,specially about physics

Comment: Hm. Does anyone know if softbody physics works on rigged objects?