# Squish Object Towards Surface

Tags: sculpting

I have a model of a cat of which I want to make a sculpture. For it to stand steadily and not rock on any surface I put it on I want to, in a smooth way, flatten the bottom surfaces to a common level plane.

In the attached image you can see the underside of the cat. You can see how the paws are clearly flattened towards the bottom as if the cat is resting on something. This is exaclty what I want but  for the tail as well. It is also extremely important that the tail and feet are flattened against the same plane as the cat would not sit well on a flat surface otherwise.

Is there a good way of doing this smoothly (wityhout a sharp boundary between organic shapes and the flat surface)? This requirement of a smooth organic boundary rules out boolean operations unfortunately.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: have you tried to select the bottom of the tail, enable the Proportional Editing option and scale on the Z axis? You can also try with the Lattice modifier and same thing, enable the Proportional Editing

Comment: something like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109431/how-to-achieve-pressing-against-invisible-wall-effect-facing-camera-animation/165689#165689

Comment: This seems like it might work. I'll have to try it out to know for sure. Thanks!